# How to read ID3 tags from SD card in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, id3

In an Ionic 3 app, I am trying to read ID3 tags from files stored on the SD card. I tried to use [jsmediatags](https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags) but only get various errors, including crashes.

I am able to import jsmediatags properly with:

```
import * as jsmediatags from 'jsmediatags';
```

The typical call to read a file's tags would be similar to this:

```
const localFile: string = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/song.mp3';
jsmediatags.read(localFile, {
  onSuccess: function(tags) {
    console.log('RESOLVED - jsmediatags.read');
    console.log(tags);
  },
  onError: function(error) {
    console.log('REJECTED - jsmediatags.read');
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

This always fails.

I must say that I am perfectly able to play this same file with the [Ionic native Media](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/) plugin. The path is correct, the file is playable and contains ID3 tags.

Note: I am only after Android compatibility (for the moment).

Comment: Can you solve it?

Comment: No I gave up on this for now because it was not a paid project... :(   I would still like to find a solution!